# Azure Keyvault configuration value always returned null dotnet core 2.1

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

My app is MVC Core 2.1 application, I followed steps from this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.1

First in azure I've registred my application and get my three parameters the KeyVault, the appID and the appSecret and I put them in a json file that I named azurekeyvault.json here is its content

```
{
  "azureKeyVault": {
    "Vault": "keyvault-XXXX",
    "ClientID": "XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX",
    "ClientSecret": "YYYY"
  }
}
```

After that I added a private method in startup.cs which I called from configure method

```
private void configAzureInit(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("azurekeyvault.json", optional: false);

        var config = builder.Build();


        builder.AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{config["azureKeyVault:Vault"]}.vault.azure.net/",
            config["azureKeyVault:ClientID"],
            config["azureKeyVault:ClientSecret"]);
        builder.Build(); 

    }
```

if I test the retrival of the parameter with

```
var conn = config["appSettings:connectionStings:parametername"];
```

There is not compilation errors and always get null value, the question is that somthing wrong with the code and did I miss some steps

Thank you

Comment: Where did you place the json file? In the root of your project? There are no compilation errors because the code is good, just the configuration isn't.

Comment: Ow, wait. Missed the fact that the file isn't marked as optional, so it can find it during runtime. Otherwise you'd have an exception there. Can you check the config? I don't think object:key is the correct syntax. You have to use object.key. If that also fails, try removing the object from the json and just use the key to load them.

Comment: Where do you get null value? You could not get clientId in appsettings.json or get could not get value from Azure portal appsetting?